# Loading files from external directories with embedded lua in C++ ?

Tags: c++, file, lua, directory

I'm writing a basic scripting system using lua in C++. One of my glue functions is called from this:

```
lua_register(luaVM, "openFile", l_dial.l_specifyF);
```

And is coded as follows:

```
static int l_specifyF(lua_State* luaVM) {
    const char* c = lua_tostring(luaVM, -1);
    cDialogManager::getSingletonPtr()->clearVector();
    try{
        luaL_dofile(luaVM, c);
    } 

    catch(...) {
        cout << "Unable to open file" << endl;
        luaL_dofile(luaVM, "startup.lua");
    }
    return 1;
}
```

When I call it in my application, it works 100% if I call a file from a local directory like `openFile("somefile.lua")` or `openFile("someotherfile.lua")`, but crashes when calling files located in external folders such as `openFile("scripts/ohdear.lua")`.

**Note** that this *does* actually work on some occasions, which only adds to the confusion. Are there any reasons for this?
How can I remedy my application to use files from external directories?

Comment: are you sure you are in the correct working directory?

Comment: Yeah positive, like I said it works sometimes, maybe like 10%~. Also if the file doesn't exist it puts out the "Unable..." message, but with the errors I am getting it acts as if it has loaded the file.

Comment: Why don't you catch and print out any errors returned by luaL_dofile?

Comment: What happens if you do `assert(io.open("marker.tmp","w")):close()`, or better yet `assert(io.open("scripts/marker.tmp","w")):close()`, where `marker.tmp` is a suitable unique name for a not-yet-existing file. If it executes without error, where in your filesystem did it get created?

Comment: They get created in the correct locations (When it does work...) think it might be what towi said below, will have to ensure im not bringing any errors with me from before, specifically the text input functions...

Comment: Is the current directory fixed or mutable in the app's lifetime? For instance, in Windows, the Standard File Open dialog actually changes the current working directory under some circumstances. This can be surprising, and has led to a tendency in Windows app development to never trust pathnames that are not fully qualified.

Answer (score 0):

From your description I seriously doubt that it has something to do with folder struction. My guess is, that you are observing an late reaction from an earlier error...

Comment: I think you are probably right, will have a root around and see if I can uncover the problem.

Comment: You could try using `valgrind` to check for bad memory accesses in your program.